# Media Foundation: Media session

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ms-media-foundation, multimedia

I want to create an application using Media foundation's media session techniques. What is the exact difference between using Source reader and media session?

thanks in advance,

Sri

Answer (score 3):

**Media Session** manages connections, data flow and other critical stuff (buffers etc.) between Media Source, Media Foundation Transform and Media Sink components which are essential parts of a multimedia pipeline under Windows.

**Source Reader** is an alternative to Media Session and is optimized for playback. So, while creating simple playback applications, you might want to consider Source Reader.

Please look into following for more details.

- [Media Foundation MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694197%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Source Reader Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd940436%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Media Session Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms703988%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)